# Maximum and minimum value in record Pascal

Tags: arrays, record, pascal, freepascal

So I want to print the maximum and minimum scores in various exam (as you can see in my maximum and minimum function)

How to print maximum and minimum value in maksimum and minimum function in my code, cause it always giving value of 0? anybody can help?

This is my code

```
program data_nilai_mhs;

uses crt;
type mhs = record
     nama,nim,tgl:string;
     tugas,prak,uas,uts:integer;
     akhir:real;
     end;

var dtmhs:array [1..35] of mhs;
    i,a,uts_max,uas_max,uts_min,uas_min  :integer;
    akhir_min,akhir_max:Real;
    grade:string;
    pilih:integer;

procedure input;

begin
  clrscr;
  writeln(' ');
  writeln(' MASUKKAN DATA NILAI MAHASISWA ');
  writeln(' ----------------------------- ');
  write  (' Jumlah Mahasiswa : '); readln(a);
  writeln;
  for i:=1 to a do
  begin
  with dtmhs[i] do
     begin
     writeln(' Data Ke-',i);
     writeln(' ----------- ');
     write  (' Nama      : '); readln (dtmhs[i].nama);
     write  (' NIM       : '); readln (dtmhs[i].nim);
     write  (' Tugas     : '); readln (dtmhs[i].tugas);
     write  (' UTS       : '); readln (dtmhs[i].uts);
     write  (' UAS       : '); readln (dtmhs[i].uas);
     write  (' Praktikum : '); readln (dtmhs[i].prak);
     writeln;
     readln;
     end;
  end;
end;

procedure tabel;
begin
  writeln(' ');
  writeln('|===============================================================================================================|');
  writeln('|                    DATA NILAI MAHASISWA                                                                       |');
  writeln('|===============================================================================================================|');
  writeln('|NO.|  NAMA MAHASISWA  |     NIM     |   TUGAS   |   UTS   |    UAS   |    PRAK    |      NA       |    GRADE   |');
  writeln('|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|');
  for i:=1 to a do
  begin
  gotoxy(1,i+6);
  writeln('|   |                  |             |           |         |          |            |               |            |');
  writeln('|===============================================================================================================|');
  end;
end;

// Fungsi Maksimum
function utsmax(): Integer;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].uts > dtmhs[max].uts) then max := i;  
  end;
  utsmax:=dtmhs[max].uts;
end;


function uasmax(): Integer;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].uas > dtmhs[max].uas) then max := i;  
  end;
  uasmax:=dtmhs[max].uas;
end;

function tugasmax(): Integer;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].tugas > dtmhs[max].tugas) then max := i;  
  end;
  tugasmax:=dtmhs[max].tugas;
end;

function prakmax(): Integer;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].prak > dtmhs[max].prak) then max := i;  
  end;
  prakmax:=dtmhs[max].prak;
end;

function namax(): Real;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].akhir > dtmhs[max].akhir) then max := i;  
  end;
  namax:=dtmhs[max].akhir;
end;

// Fungsi minimum
function utsmin(): Integer;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].uts < dtmhs[min].uts) then min := i;  
  end;
  utsmin:=dtmhs[min].uts;
end;


function uasmin(): Integer;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].uas < dtmhs[min].uas) then min := i;  
  end;
  uasmin:=dtmhs[min].uas;
end;

function tugasmin(): Integer;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].tugas < dtmhs[min].tugas) then min := i;  
  end;
  tugasmin:=dtmhs[min].tugas;
end;

function prakmin(): Integer;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].prak < dtmhs[min].prak) then min := i;  
  end;
  prakmin:=dtmhs[min].prak;
end;

function namin(): Real;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].akhir < dtmhs[min].akhir) then min := i;  
  end;
  namin:=dtmhs[min].akhir;
end;

function maksimum(): Integer;
var
  chose: Char;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('a. Nilai UTS      ');
  writeln('b. Nilai UAS      ');
  writeln('c. Nilai Tugas    ');
  writeln('d. Nilai Praktikum');
  writeln('e. Nilai Akhir    ');
  write  ('Masukkan Pilihan [a/b/c/d/e] ? : ');readln(chose);
  case chose of
    'a': writeln('Nilai terbesar UTS adalah ',utsmax());
    'b': writeln('Nilai terbesar UAS adalah ',uasmax());
    'c': writeln('Nilai terbesar Tugas  adalah ',tugasmax());
    'd': writeln('Nilai terbesar Praktikum adalah ',prakmax());
    'e': writeln('Nilai terbesar NA adalah ',namax():0:2);
  end;
end;

function minimum(): Integer;
var
  chose: Char;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('a. Nilai UTS      ');
  writeln('b. Nilai UAS      ');
  writeln('c. Nilai Tugas    ');
  writeln('d. Nilai Praktikum');
  writeln('e. Nilai Akhir    ');
  write  ('Masukkan Pilihan [a/b/c/d/e] ? : ');readln(chose);
  case chose of
    'a': writeln('Nilai terbesar UTS adalah ',utsmin());
    'b': writeln('Nilai terbesar UAS adalah ',uasmin());
    'c': writeln('Nilai terbesar Tugas  adalah ',tugasmin());
    'd': writeln('Nilai terbesar Praktikum adalah ',prakmin());
    'e': writeln('Nilai terbesar NA adalah ',namin():0:2);
  end;
end;

function rerata_uts():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].uts;
    end;
    rerata_uts:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_uas():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].uas;
    end;
    rerata_uas:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_tugas():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].tugas;
    end;
    rerata_tugas:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_prak():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].prak;
    end;
    rerata_prak:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_akhir():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].akhir;
    end;
    rerata_akhir:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_semua(): real;
var
  chose: Char;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('a. Rata-rata UTS      ');
  writeln('b. Rata-rata UAS      ');
  writeln('c. Rata-rata Tugas    ');
  writeln('d. Rata-rata Praktikum');
  writeln('e. Rata-rata Akhir    ');
  write  ('Masukkan Pilihan [a/b/c/d/e] ? : ');readln(chose);
  case chose of
    'a': writeln('Nilai rata-rata UTS adalah ',rerata_uts():0:2);
    'b': writeln('Nilai rata-rata UAS adalah ',rerata_uas():0:2);
    'c': writeln('Nilai rata-rata Tugas  adalah ',rerata_tugas():0:2);
    'd': writeln('Nilai rata-rata Praktikum adalah ',rerata_prak():0:2);
    'e': writeln('Nilai rata-rata NA adalah ',rerata_akhir():0:2);
  end;
end;
procedure output;
var
  chose: Integer;
 begin
 clrscr;
 tabel;
 for i:=1 to a do
 begin
   dtmhs[i].akhir := (0.1*dtmhs[i].tugas) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].uts) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].uas) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].prak);
   with dtmhs[i] do
   begin
        if (akhir>=0)  and (akhir < 20) then grade:='E' else
        if (akhir>=20) and (akhir < 40) then grade:='D' else
        if (akhir>=40) and (akhir < 60) then grade:='C' else
        if (akhir>=60) and (akhir < 80) then grade:='B' else
        grade:='A' ;
   end;
 end;
 for i:=1 to a do
 begin
   with dtmhs[i] do
   begin
     gotoxy(3,i+6); writeln(i);
     gotoxy(9,i+6); writeln(nama);
     gotoxy(26,i+6);writeln(nim);
     gotoxy(43,i+6);writeln(tugas);
     gotoxy(56,i+6);writeln(uts);
     gotoxy(69,i+6);writeln(uas);
     gotoxy(82,i+6);writeln(prak);
     gotoxy(95,i+6);writeln(akhir:0:2);
     gotoxy(108,i+6);writeln(grade);
   end;
 end;
 readln;
end;

begin
  // repeat
  clrscr;
  writeln('|     SELAMAT DATANG DI PROGRAM ENTRI MAHASISWA     |');
  writeln('|===================================================|');
  writeln('|                                                   |');
  writeln('| 1. Input Data Mahasiswa                           |');
  writeln('| 2. Tampilan Data Mahasiswa                        |');
  writeln('| 3. Nilai Alpro Terbesar                           |');
  writeln('| 4. Nilai Alpro Terkecil                           |');
  writeln('| 5. Rata-rata Nilai Alpro                          |');
  writeln('| 6. Keluar                                         |');
  writeln('|===================================================|');
  writeln(' ');
  write  ('Masukkan Pilihan [1/2/3/4/5/6] ? : ');readln(pilih);
      case pilih of
      1 : input;
      2 : output;
      3 : maksimum;
      4 : minimum;
      5 : rerata_semua();
      6 : writeln('Terima kasih');
      end;
  // until pilih=6;
  write('Ingin menampilkan apa[2/3/4/5/6] ?');readln(pilih);
  case pilih of
    2: output;
    3: maksimum;
    4: minimum;
    5: rerata_semua();
    6: writeln('Terima kasih');
  end;
end.
```

*Edit
This is my code so far

I can get the everything except for the `namax`, `namin` and `rerata_akhir` function. They all return 0 value instead of the calculated formula below

`dtmhs[i].akhir := (0.1*dtmhs[i].tugas) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].uts) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].uas) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].prak);`

How can I do with this?Thanks in advance

```
program data_nilai_mhs;

uses crt;
type mhs = record
     nama,nim,tgl:string;
     tugas,prak,uas,uts:integer;
     akhir:real;
     end;

var dtmhs:array [1..35] of mhs;
    i,a,uts_max,uas_max,uts_min,uas_min  :integer;
    akhir_min,akhir_max:Real;
    grade:string;
    pilih:integer;

procedure input;

begin
  clrscr;
  writeln(' ');
  writeln(' MASUKKAN DATA NILAI MAHASISWA ');
  writeln(' ----------------------------- ');
  write  (' Jumlah Mahasiswa : '); readln(a);
  writeln;
  for i:=1 to a do
  begin
  with dtmhs[i] do
     begin
     writeln(' Data Ke-',i);
     writeln(' ----------- ');
     write  (' Nama      : '); readln (dtmhs[i].nama);
     write  (' NIM       : '); readln (dtmhs[i].nim);
     write  (' Tugas     : '); readln (dtmhs[i].tugas);
     write  (' UTS       : '); readln (dtmhs[i].uts);
     write  (' UAS       : '); readln (dtmhs[i].uas);
     write  (' Praktikum : '); readln (dtmhs[i].prak);
     writeln;
     readln;
     end;
  end;
end;

procedure tabel;
begin
  writeln(' ');
  writeln('|===============================================================================================================|');
  writeln('|                    DATA NILAI MAHASISWA                                                                       |');
  writeln('|===============================================================================================================|');
  writeln('|NO.|  NAMA MAHASISWA  |     NIM     |   TUGAS   |   UTS   |    UAS   |    PRAK    |      NA       |    GRADE   |');
  writeln('|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|');
  for i:=1 to a do
  begin
  gotoxy(1,i+6);
  writeln('|   |                  |             |           |         |          |            |               |            |');
  writeln('|===============================================================================================================|');
  end;
end;

// Fungsi Maksimum
function utsmax(): Integer;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].uts > dtmhs[max].uts) then max := i;  
  end;
  utsmax:=dtmhs[max].uts;
end;


function uasmax(): Integer;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].uas > dtmhs[max].uas) then max := i;  
  end;
  uasmax:=dtmhs[max].uas;
end;

function tugasmax(): Integer;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].tugas > dtmhs[max].tugas) then max := i;  
  end;
  tugasmax:=dtmhs[max].tugas;
end;

function prakmax(): Integer;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].prak > dtmhs[max].prak) then max := i;  
  end;
  prakmax:=dtmhs[max].prak;
end;

function namax(): Real;
var
    max:Integer;
begin
  max:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].akhir > dtmhs[max].akhir) then max := i;  
  end;
  namax:=dtmhs[max].akhir;
end;

// Fungsi minimum
function utsmin(): Integer;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].uts < dtmhs[min].uts) then min := i;  
  end;
  utsmin:=dtmhs[min].uts;
end;


function uasmin(): Integer;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].uas < dtmhs[min].uas) then min := i;  
  end;
  uasmin:=dtmhs[min].uas;
end;

function tugasmin(): Integer;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].tugas < dtmhs[min].tugas) then min := i;  
  end;
  tugasmin:=dtmhs[min].tugas;
end;

function prakmin(): Integer;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].prak < dtmhs[min].prak) then min := i;  
  end;
  prakmin:=dtmhs[min].prak;
end;

function namin(): Real;
var
    min:Integer;
begin
  min:=1;
  for i := 2 to a do 
  begin
    if (dtmhs[i].akhir < dtmhs[min].akhir) then min := i;  
  end;
  namin:=dtmhs[min].akhir;
end;

function maksimum(): Integer;
var
  chose: Char;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('a. Nilai UTS      ');
  writeln('b. Nilai UAS      ');
  writeln('c. Nilai Tugas    ');
  writeln('d. Nilai Praktikum');
  writeln('e. Nilai Akhir    ');
  write  ('Masukkan Pilihan [a/b/c/d/e] ? : ');readln(chose);
  case chose of
    'a': writeln('Nilai terbesar UTS adalah ',utsmax());
    'b': writeln('Nilai terbesar UAS adalah ',uasmax());
    'c': writeln('Nilai terbesar Tugas  adalah ',tugasmax());
    'd': writeln('Nilai terbesar Praktikum adalah ',prakmax());
    'e': writeln('Nilai terbesar NA adalah ',namax():0:2);
  end;
end;

function minimum(): Integer;
var
  chose: Char;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('a. Nilai UTS      ');
  writeln('b. Nilai UAS      ');
  writeln('c. Nilai Tugas    ');
  writeln('d. Nilai Praktikum');
  writeln('e. Nilai Akhir    ');
  write  ('Masukkan Pilihan [a/b/c/d/e] ? : ');readln(chose);
  case chose of
    'a': writeln('Nilai terbesar UTS adalah ',utsmin());
    'b': writeln('Nilai terbesar UAS adalah ',uasmin());
    'c': writeln('Nilai terbesar Tugas  adalah ',tugasmin());
    'd': writeln('Nilai terbesar Praktikum adalah ',prakmin());
    'e': writeln('Nilai terbesar NA adalah ',namin():0:2);
  end;
end;

function rerata_uts():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].uts;
    end;
    rerata_uts:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_uas():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].uas;
    end;
    rerata_uas:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_tugas():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].tugas;
    end;
    rerata_tugas:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_prak():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].prak;
    end;
    rerata_prak:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_akhir():real;
var 
    temp:real;
begin
    temp:=0;
    for i:=1 to a do begin
        temp:=temp+dtmhs[i].akhir;
    end;
    rerata_akhir:=temp/a;
end;

function rerata_semua(): real;
var
  chose: Char;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('a. Rata-rata UTS      ');
  writeln('b. Rata-rata UAS      ');
  writeln('c. Rata-rata Tugas    ');
  writeln('d. Rata-rata Praktikum');
  writeln('e. Rata-rata Akhir    ');
  write  ('Masukkan Pilihan [a/b/c/d/e] ? : ');readln(chose);
  case chose of
    'a': writeln('Nilai rata-rata UTS adalah ',rerata_uts():0:2);
    'b': writeln('Nilai rata-rata UAS adalah ',rerata_uas():0:2);
    'c': writeln('Nilai rata-rata Tugas  adalah ',rerata_tugas():0:2);
    'd': writeln('Nilai rata-rata Praktikum adalah ',rerata_prak():0:2);
    'e': writeln('Nilai rata-rata NA adalah ',rerata_akhir():0:2);
  end;
end;
procedure output;
var
  chose: Integer;
 begin
 clrscr;
 tabel;
 for i:=1 to a do
 begin
   dtmhs[i].akhir := (0.1*dtmhs[i].tugas) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].uts) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].uas) + (0.3*dtmhs[i].prak);
   with dtmhs[i] do
   begin
        if (akhir>=0)  and (akhir < 20) then grade:='E' else
        if (akhir>=20) and (akhir < 40) then grade:='D' else
        if (akhir>=40) and (akhir < 60) then grade:='C' else
        if (akhir>=60) and (akhir < 80) then grade:='B' else
        grade:='A' ;
   end;
 end;
 for i:=1 to a do
 begin
   with dtmhs[i] do
   begin
     gotoxy(3,i+6); writeln(i);
     gotoxy(9,i+6); writeln(nama);
     gotoxy(26,i+6);writeln(nim);
     gotoxy(43,i+6);writeln(tugas);
     gotoxy(56,i+6);writeln(uts);
     gotoxy(69,i+6);writeln(uas);
     gotoxy(82,i+6);writeln(prak);
     gotoxy(95,i+6);writeln(akhir:0:2);
     gotoxy(108,i+6);writeln(grade);
   end;
 end;
 readln;
end;

begin
  // repeat
  clrscr;
  writeln('|     SELAMAT DATANG DI PROGRAM ENTRI MAHASISWA     |');
  writeln('|===================================================|');
  writeln('|                                                   |');
  writeln('| 1. Input Data Mahasiswa                           |');
  writeln('| 2. Tampilan Data Mahasiswa                        |');
  writeln('| 3. Nilai Alpro Terbesar                           |');
  writeln('| 4. Nilai Alpro Terkecil                           |');
  writeln('| 5. Rata-rata Nilai Alpro                          |');
  writeln('| 6. Keluar                                         |');
  writeln('|===================================================|');
  writeln(' ');
  write  ('Masukkan Pilihan [1/2/3/4/5/6] ? : ');readln(pilih);
      case pilih of
      1 : input;
      2 : output;
      3 : maksimum;
      4 : minimum;
      5 : rerata_semua();
      6 : writeln('Terima kasih');
      end;
  // until pilih=6;
  write('Ingin menampilkan apa[2/3/4/5/6] ?');readln(pilih);
  case pilih of
    2: output;
    3: maksimum;
    4: minimum;
    5: rerata_semua();
    6: writeln('Terima kasih');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: You should debug your program. It's very hard to write code without debugging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `function maksimum(): integer;` you print `uts_max`, `uas_max` and `akhir_max`, but you never assign any value to these variables.

In the `for i := 2 to a do` loop you want to write

```
if (dtmhs[i].uas > uas_max) then uas_max := dtmhs[i].uas;
```

Similar changes to the other values.

In `function maksimum(): integer;` you attempt to initialize the `uts_min`, `uas_min` and `akhir_min` like this:

```
dtmhs[1].uts := uts_min;
dtmhs[1].uas := uas_min;
dtmhs[1].akhir := akhir_min;
```

which is opposite to what you need to do. You should instead do

```
uts_min := dtmhs[1].uts;
uas_min := dtmhs[1].uas;
akhir_min := dtmhs[1].akhir;
```

and also change the search for min values like this:

```
if (dtmhs[i].uas < uas_min) then uas_min := dtmhs[i].uas;
```

again, same for the other values.

Comment: This method works, but I managed to create each value to a function. Thanks for the answer

Comment: But why my akhir_max and akhir_min value is still 0 ?

Comment: There are two possibilities, either you never assign anything to `akhir_max` and `akhir_min` (no code like akhir_max := something) or the `dtmhs[i].akhir` values are all zero

Comment: I just edit my question to show you my latest code, can you find what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why `dtmhs[i].akhir` can't stored any value?

Comment: Yess, it is like weighted mean value. And in my latest code, the procedure output called after the maximum and minimum calculation. What's happening then?

Comment: Dio, it is not according to the rules of Stack Overflow to continue modifying your question and asking new details. I have answered your original question, and even extended to your additional question once. If you have further matters, post a new question.

Comment: Ohh my bad, I'll post a new question later. For the n it is should be a not n, I'm sorry